# how to exclude one namespace prefix from matching?

Tags: xslt

using xslt 1.0 
i want exlude pma:database and pma:table from matching, i added exclude-result-prefixes but it seems to have no effect.

i dont need to transform the configuration section of the xml.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
- phpMyAdmin XML Dump
- version 4.1.7
- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-
- Host: localhost
- Generation Time: Dic 07, 2015 alle 16:57
- Versione del server: 5.1.71-community-log
- PHP Version: 5.3.10
-->

<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
<!--
- Structure schemas
-->
<pma:structure_schemas>
    <pma:database name="my_professioneslot" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
        <pma:table name="Slots">
            CREATE TABLE `Slots` (
              `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `IdProduttore` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `Scheda` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `NomeCommerciale` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `Produttore2` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `CodiceModello` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `PercMinima` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `Ciclo` int(11) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
        </pma:table>
    </pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas>

<!--
- Database: 'my_professioneslot'
-->
<database name="my_professioneslot">
    <!-- Tabella Slots -->
    <table name="Slots">
        <column name="ID">1</column>
        <column name="IdProduttore">1</column>
        <column name="Scheda">GOOD LUCK ULTIMATE</column>
        <column name="NomeCommerciale">CASINO' GOOD LUCK ULTIMATE</column>
        <column name="Produttore2">0</column>
        <column name="CodiceModello">776870592765183</column>
        <column name="PercMinima">75</column>
        <column name="Ciclo">30000</column>
    </table>
    <table name="Slots">
        <column name="ID">2</column>
        <column name="IdProduttore">1</column>
        <column name="Scheda">MEGA DOBLONE</column>
        <column name="NomeCommerciale">CASINO' MEGA DOBLONE</column>
        <column name="Produttore2">0</column>
        <column name="CodiceModello">776870592865184</column>
        <column name="PercMinima">75</column>
        <column name="Ciclo">30000</column>
    </table>
```

xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl pma">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="database">
  <xsl:element name="produttori">
  <xsl:for-each select="table">
    <xsl:element name="produttore" >
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="column[@name='ID']"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="column[@name='Descrizione']"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

result:

```
            CREATE TABLE `Slots` (
              `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `IdProduttore` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `Scheda` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `NomeCommerciale` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `Produttore2` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `CodiceModello` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `PercMinima` int(11) NOT NULL,
              `Ciclo` int(11) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;





<produttori><produttore id="1"></produttore><produttore id="2"></produttore></produttori>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude-result-prefixes` only useful to exclude prefix declaration from the output XML, when the prefix is not used. If you want to remove certain elements i.e elements in certain namespace, you can use empty template that match such element, for example :

```
<xsl:template match="pma:*"/>
```

The above well remove all elements in the namespace that referenced by the prefix `pma`